# How do I configure Git to pull from one repo and push to another?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I've cloned a public GitHub repo [remote origin] for a class I'm taking and pull my assignments from it.  After I do the assignments I'd like to push my work to a private BitBucket repo [remote bitbucket] which I created with the commands (fake repo name):

```
$ git remote add bitbucket https://neilostrove@bitbucket.org/neilostrove/bb-repo.git
$ git push -u bitbucket --all
Password:
Counting objects: 2856, done.
...
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from bitbucket.
Branch work set up to track remote branch work from bitbucket.
$ git push -u bitbucket --tags
Password:
Everything up-to-date
$
```

Now when I try to pull from origin I get the message:

```
$ git pull origin
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

I would like to set things up so that when I pull (or fetch) my repo gets updated from origin, and when I push everything is pushed to bitbucket.  How can I do that?

This is how I have my remotes set up:

```
 $ git remote -v
 bitbucket       https://neilostrove@bitbucket.org/neilostrove/bb-repo.git (fetch)
 bitbucket       https://neilostrove@bitbucket.org/neilostrove/bb-repo.git (push)
 origin  https://github.com/instructor/gh-repo.git (fetch)
 origin  https://github.com/instructor/gh-repo.git (push)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use is common enough there's a config item:

> `git config remote.branch.pushurl u://r/l`

Documentation at the [git-config(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) and [git-push(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html).

Comment: I looked at the man pages but I don't see how setting a pushurl fixes the pull issue.

Comment: Reset a branch's upstream with e.g. [`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master mybranch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).

Comment: Thanks.  My Git 1.7.7 didn't understand `set-upstream-to` but `$ git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` seemed to work for me.