# Pull from one branch and push to another on git

Tags: git, github, git-config

I need to be able to pull from one branch and push to another. In this case, I need to be able to pull from a stable 'master' branch and push to a branch named 'stage'. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814084/how-do-i-configure-git-to-pull-from-one-repo-and-push-to-another) and it explains how I can push to a remote branch. If I am on the 'stage' branch, how do I pull from the master branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Pull from other branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257196/git-pull-from-other-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `git pull` is a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.

What you want is to merge `master` instead of the default `stage` when you would call `git pull` on the `stage` branch.

So

```
git fetch [origin master]
git merge master
```

should do the trick.